# How to include only flavor specific resource in apk

Tags: android, cordova

I am using Android Studio 1.5.1 with Gradle version 2.8. My android cordova project has 3 flavors and the directory structure I follow is this :

```
src > main > res  
src > Flavor1 > res  
src > Flavor2 > res  
src > Flavor3 > res
```

My android .gradle file is pretty straight forward with relevant closures defined for each of the three flavors defining just the ApplicationId values

Although each flavor shows correct graphics as per their respective res folders, the problem is when I generate signed apk for a single flavor, the apk contains res items from all the four directories above, unnecessarily increasing the weight of the apk file. How do I configure the system to include only say, Flavor1 res files when generating apk for Flavor1 ?

Comment: The problem with flavors is that they get merged before the build. The `main > res` should contain all shared data/resources, and the `flavor > res` should contain only flavor-specific data/resources. So you may have been using flavors incorrectly from the beginning.

Comment: I wish to completely override the res in each flavor. Even if I remove the contains of main > res, what do I do about the other Flavor res folders ?? All res folders show up all apks, instead of appearing only in the flavor specific apk. 

What is the correct use of flavors in my scenario ?

Comment: Set a Gradle task to delete all other (unused) `res` folders from `immediates` before building. Your scenario isn't how flavors were designed to be used :/ But regardless, they can still be used like that with a bit of hacking :)

Comment: I will give that a try, thanks ..

Comment: BTW, I forgot to mention all the 4 res folders have the exact same structure and the exact same file names. I guess this should have prompted the build system to use only flavor specific res files in final apk, it just feels like the logical thing to do :-)

Comment: If all your resources are "flavor-specific" then you don't have any flavor-specific resources really... You have many projects bundled as one project.

Comment: The codebase remains the same, only some images need to change between flavors ... I would think its the same project